# Remove inherited required attribute on data attributes in razor pages

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-2.0, data-annotations, razor-pages

I have a model with a few attributes that are either decimals or doubles. I don't want them to be required but I can't figure out a way to disable the inheritance of the required attribute.

Here is a snippet from the razor pages validation documentation:

> The Required and MinimumLength attributes indicate that a property must have a value. However, nothing prevents a user from entering whitespace to satisfy the validation constraint for a nullable type. Non-nullable value types (such as decimal, int, float, and DateTime) are inherently required and don't need the Required attribute.

```
// Model
public class Foo 
{
    public decimal SomeRate {get; set;}
}

// Page
<form method="post">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="BuyAndHoldReport.Mortgage" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="BuyAndHoldReport.Mortgage" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="BuyAndHoldReport.Mortgage" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
         <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-success" />
    </div>
</form>
```

Edit:

- I want to try avoid making the attributes nullable because I want them to be saved with their default value and not null
- I want to try avoid defaulting the values when loading the page because if the user edits one of the attributes I don't want them having to remember the default value before they changed it if they want to unset it.

Answer (score 1):

For removing `Required` on `Non-NullAble` value types, you could add `?` to the property to make it `NullAble`.

Something like below

```
public decimal? SomeRate { get; set; }
```

Comment: thanks for this but I would like to avoid doing this because i want the value to default to 0.0m rather than null.